# Override Javascript of Telerik Controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have `RadTimePicker` Control in `WebApplication`.

is it possible to override inbuit javascript ?

i have added RadTImepicker control.

when i enter invalid time using keyboard it displays small image.

so i think this validation is done via inbuilt `javascript` of `telerik controls.`
i just want to change the location of image.

is it possible to see the inbuilt `javascript` or can i override it ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the following cSS to change position of image
CSS:

```
    .riError[type="text"]
    {
        background:white 70% -298px no-repeat url('WebResource.axd?d=Sb8o_12Aonrr6SbuYLrVntkCbjA6FwxXFPzfuUFl5aKUhbtAgRkTMDov2XT3kgwpPfkaP7u3AcioQm7TVFu-HUgOZmXnrx718rM70i_3H9El66Y1O4cKTvAVD01ROWRKAnMUJy5qlfw-HrhcORo36YN2hAZFL5tdo9zFQGdci0Y1&t=634950539760000000') !important;
    }
```

here change the values of 70% by default it is 100%

Thanks
AB